# How to make a control disappear that doesn't fit into the bounds of its parent

Tags: wpf, vb.net, panel

I'd like to create a control (`Panel`?) which can hold several child controls and arrange them. But my control should only show child controls that completely fit into the bounds of my parent control horizontally. All other child controls should not be shown at all (no scroll bar). When the size of my control increases, more child controls should become visible as soon as they fit into the increased bounds. And of course they should vanish again, if the size of my control gets decreased.

Right now I use an `ItemsControl` with a custom panel as its `ItemPanel` and this custom panel is my control.

First I tried to create a custom panel from scratch (inherit from `Panel`), but I couldn't get the measuring and arranging work all the way through.

```
Protected Overrides Function MeasureOverride(availableSize As Size) As Size
    Dim result As Size

    For Each child As UIElement In Me.InternalChildren
        child.Measure(availableSize)

        result.Width += child.DesiredSize.Width
        result.Height = Math.Max(result.Height, child.DesiredSize.Height)
    Next child

    Return New Size(Math.Min(result.Width, availableSize.Width), Math.Min(result.Height, availableSize.Height))
End Function

Protected Overrides Function ArrangeOverride(finalSize As Size) As Size
    Dim left As Double
    Dim bounds As Rect

    left = 0.0

    For Each child As UIElement In Me.InternalChildren
        If ((left + child.DesiredSize.Width) > finalSize.Width) Then
            child.Arrange(New Rect)
        Else
            bounds = New Rect
            bounds.X = left
            bounds.Y = 0
            bounds.Width = child.DesiredSize.Width
            bounds.Height = child.DesiredSize.Height

            child.Arrange(bounds)
        End If

        left += child.DesiredSize.Width
    Next child

    Return finalSize
End Function
```

This seems to work the way I want it. But as soon as there is only one child left and the size gets too small to even show this one child, it doesn't vanish. The reason is that in the `MeasureOverride` the `availableSize` (the too small one) is used to measure the child, so the `DesiredSize` of this child fits into the (too small) `availableSize`.

Then I tried to use a horizontal `StackPanel` and override just the `ArrangeOverride`, let the `StackPanel` do the arranging and decide afterwards, whether to remove a child (`Visibility` = Collapsed) or not. But I can't find a way to decide whether a child fits into the bounds of its parent or not, because I can't find the information about the "position" of the child inside its parent. There's a `VisualOffset` property that looks promising but I can't access it.

I thought about overriding `OnRenderSizeChanged` instead of `ArrangeOverride`, but there I would have the same problem, how to decide whether a child fits into the bounds of its parent.

Can you give me a hint on how to do what I like to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching I decided to go with the horizontal `StackPanel` and overriding the `ArrangeOverride`. I access the not accessible `VisualOffset` property by reflection (I know, it's frowned upon) to detect the position of the arranged child and to decide whether it's still visible or not.

```
Protected Overrides Function ArrangeOverride(arrangeSize As Size) As Size
    Dim result As Size
    Dim visualOffset As Vector

    result = MyBase.ArrangeOverride(arrangeSize)

    For Each element As UIElement In MyBase.InternalChildren
        visualOffset = element.GetType.GetProperty("VisualOffset", BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(element)

        If visualOffset.X + element.DesiredSize.Width > MyBase.DesiredSize.Width Then
            element.Arrange(New Rect)   'hide the element without breaking possible Visibility bindings
        End If
    Next element

    Return result
End Function
```